# Generalising functions defined only for certain remainder classes.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, soft-question, modular-arithmetic

I'm currently working with a particular function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ but I determined its expression only by diving it in three separate functions defined by the remainder of the input value modulo 3.

More clearly said, $f(n) =
     \begin{cases}
      f_0(n) ~~~~~~~~ \forall n \equiv0 \mod 3 \\
      f_1(n) ~~~~~~~~ \forall n \equiv1 \mod 3 \\
      f_2(n) ~~~~~~~~ \forall n \equiv2 \mod 3 \\
      \end{cases}\,$

Considering that all $f_0,f_1f_2$ are injective and having a real image, I'd like to work out a general formula for $f(n)$ without having a separate case for each congruence class.

I'm tagging this question as soft-question because I'm satisfied just with some resource to read or some particular technique that allows me to generalise this.

In this particular case $f_1,f_2$ and $f_3$ are all square roots of a polynomial, if that's useful, but I would be glad to find out a general solution to this problem.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I'm sorry if I misunderstood you, but can't I just have $\exp(\frac{2 \pi i}{3} n) $ as $L_0$ and likewise $\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{3} (n-1)) $ for $L_1$ and so on? The problem is if I do this the resulting function doesn't return the same values as the previous ones defined in their congruence class. Please reply because I need to have a singular function without having cases. I would really be happy with a function having separate cases but I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a $3$-periodic sequence, $u_n=\exp(2ni\pi/3)=j^n$, with $j=\exp(2i\pi/3)$.

Let

$$L_0(z)=\dfrac{(z-u_1)(z-u_2)}{(u_0-u_1)(u_0-u_2)}=\frac13(1+z+z^2)$$
$$L_1(z)=\dfrac{(z-u_0)(z-u_2)}{(u_1-u_0)(u_1-u_2)}=L_0(z\exp(-2i\pi/3))$$
$$L_2(z)=\dfrac{(z-u_0)(z-u_1)}{(u_2-u_0)(u_2-u_1)}=L_0(z\exp(2i\pi/3))$$

Then $L_0(u_n)=1$ if $n\equiv 0 \pmod3$ and $0$ otherwise. Likewise $L_1(u_n)=1$ if $n\equiv 1 \pmod3$, and $L_2(u_n)=1$ if $n\equiv 2\pmod3$, and $0$ otherwise. These are three $3$-periodic functions with repeating pattern $(1,0,0)$ (resp. $(0,1,0)$ and $0,0,1$).

Now let

$$g(n)=L_0(u_n)f_0(n)+L_1(u_n)f_1(n)+L_2(u_n)f_2(n)$$

If $n\equiv0 \pmod3$, $L_1(u_n)=L_2(u_n)=0$ and $L_0(u_n)=1$, therefore $g(n)=f_0(n)$.

Likewise, if $n\equiv1\pmod 3$, $g(n)=f_1(n)$, and if $n\equiv2\pmod 3$, $g(n)=f_2(n)$.

However, this is only a trick. Unless further simplifications are possible with $f_0, f_1, f_2$ (which is unlikely, given what you told), there is nothing to learn from $g$ that can't be obtained with the separate cases, i.e. $f$.

---

To answer you comment: no, you can't just let $L_0(n)=\exp(2ni\pi/3)$ then $L_0(n)f_0(n)+\cdots$. This $L_0$ would indeed be $3$-periodic, but the values do not vanish for $n\not\equiv0\pmod3$, therefore you won't get the correct sum: we must make sure one and only one term is nonzero.

What you *can* do, however, is transform the expression to make $j^n$ appear more explicitly:

$$L_0(u_n)=L_0(j^n)=\frac13(1+j^n+j^{2n})=\frac13(1+j^n+\bar j^n)$$
$$L_1(u_n)=L_0(j^{n-1})=\frac13(1+j^{n-1}+j^{2n-2})=\frac13(1+\bar j j^n+j \bar j^n)$$
$$L_2(u_n)=L_0(j^{n-2})=\frac13(1+j^{n-2}+j^{2n-1})=\frac13(1+j j^n+\bar j \bar j^n)$$

Now you may expand $g$ with respect to the terms $1$, $j^n$ and $\bar j^n$:

$$g(n)=\frac13(f_0(n)+f_1(n)+f_2(n))+\frac13(f_0(n)+\bar j f_1(n)+j f_2(n))j^n+\frac13(f_0(n)+jf_1(n)+\bar j f_2(n))\bar j^n$$

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry for my misunderstanding. i'm quite unfamiliar with this branch of math, could you give me some resource where I can study it?

Comment: @Algoak Everything here is covered by first year undergraduate maths. Actually I remember the first exam I had in first year had a similar exercise (computing the sum of $n\choose 3k$, which involves $j$ as well due to the $3$-periodicity). You need to be acquainted with Lagrange interpolation, complex numbers, congruences, and that's about all.